# What happens in OpenMP when there's a pragma for inside a pragma for?

Tags: c++, c, openmp

At the start of `#pragma omp parallel` a bunch of threads are created, then when we get to `#pragma omp for` the workload is distributed. What happens if this for loop has a for loop inside it, and I place a `#pragma omp for` before it as well? Does each thread create new threads? If not, which threads are assigned this task? What exactly happens in this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, no threads are spawned for the inner loop. It is done sequentially using the thread that reaches it.

This is because nesting is disabled by default. However, if you enable nesting via [`omp_set_nested()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk3zt8e1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), then a new set of threads will be spawned.

However, if you aren't careful, this will result in `p^2` number of threads (since each of the original `p` threads will spawn another `p` threads.) Therefore nesting is disabled by default.

Comment: I think your answer may be wrong in the sense that it address a different situation from the one asked by the OP.

Comment: @Massimiliano Hmm... good point. But I can neither confirm nor deny the UB that you claim in your answer since I seem to have a different interpretation of those two bullets.

Comment: What is your interpretation? At least, do you agree that if `n%nthreads != 0` and schedule is not `static` then point 2 is always violated?

Comment: Now that I read it again in a different context, I'm leaning a bit more towards your interpretation (+1 for pointing that out). My original interpretation is that the second bullet wasn't even applicable because the second `omp for` implied nesting. Seems ambiguous at best to me. I'd be nice if the standard clarified that. But I'm no language lawyer...

Comment: Ok, I finally found examples to support my interpretation (deep buried within the standard). See edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In a situation like the following:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
#pragma omp for
  for(int ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
    /* ... */
#pragma omp for 
    for(int jj = 0; jj < m; jj++) {
      /* ... */
    }
  }
}
```

what happens is that you trigger an undefined behavior as you violate the OpenMP standard. More precisely you violate the restrictions appearing in section 2.5 (worksharing constructs):

> The following restrictions apply to worksharing constructs:
>
> - Each worksharing region must be encountered by all threads in a team or by none at all.
> - The sequence of worksharing regions and barrier regions encountered must be the same for every thread in a team.

This is clearly shown in the examples [A.39.1c and A.40.1c](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf):

**Example A.39.1c**: The following example of loop construct nesting *is conforming* because the inner and outer loop regions bind to different parallel
regions:

```
void work(int i, int j) {}
void good_nesting(int n)
{
  int i, j;
#pragma omp parallel default(shared)
  {
#pragma omp for
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
#pragma omp parallel shared(i, n)
    {
#pragma omp for
      for (j=0; j < n; j++)
        work(i, j);
    }
    }
  }
}
```

**Example A.40.1c**: The following example is *non-conforming* because the inner and outer loop regions are closely nested

```
void work(int i, int j) {}
void wrong1(int n)
{
#pragma omp parallel default(shared)
  {
    int i, j;
#pragma omp for
    for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
    /* incorrect nesting of loop regions */
#pragma omp for
      for (j=0; j<n; j++)
        work(i, j);
    }
  }    
}
```

Notice that this is different from:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int ii = 0; ii < n; ii++) {
    /* ... */
#pragma omp parallel for 
    for(int jj = 0; jj < m; jj++) {
      /* ... */
    }
  }
```

in which you try to spawn a nested parallel region. Only in this case the discussion of Mysticial answer holds.