# OpenMP 'parallel for' with prior initialisation

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am trying to parallelize a for-loop with OpenMP. Usually this should be fairly straightforward. However I need to perform thread specific initializations prior to executing the for-loop.

Specifically I have the following problem: I have a random number generator which is not thread-safe so I need create an instance of the RNG for every thread. But I want to make sure that not every thread will produce the same random numbers.

So I tried the following:

```
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int rndseed = 42;
        #ifdef _OPENMP
            rndseed += omp_get_thread_num();
        #endif

         // initialize randon number generator

         #pragma omp for
         for (int sampleid = 0; sampleid < numsamples; ++sampleid)
         {
             // do stuff
         }
    }
```

If I use this construct I get the following error message at runtime:

> Fatal User Error 1002: '#pragma omp for' improperly nested in a work-sharing construct

So is there a way to do thread-specific initializations?

Thanks

Comment: Why not seed each RNG from `/dev/urandom`, which will give you good seeds and different values each thread?

Comment: I don't know why that's failing for you but to use random numbers see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624755/openmp-program-is-slower-than-sequential-one

Comment: The code that you are showing is not the cause of the problem. (You are not showing a work-sharing construct nested in a work-sharing construct). I expect that you actually have *another* #pragma omp for somewhere down inside "do stuff".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you have:

```
Fatal User Error 1002: '#pragma omp for' improperly nested in a work-sharing construct
```

refers to an illegal nesting of *worksharing constructs*. In fact, the OpenMP 3.1 standard gives the following restrictions in section 2.5:

> - Each worksharing region must be encountered by all threads in a team or by none at all.
> - The sequence of worksharing regions and barrier regions encountered must be the same for every thread in a team.

From the lines quoted above it follows that nesting different worksharing constructs inside the same parallel region is not conforming.

Even though the *illegal nesting* is not visible in your snippet, I assume it was hidden by an oversimplification of the post with respect to the actual code. Just to give you an hint the most common cases are:

- *loop worksharing* constructs nested inside a *single construct* (similar the example [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/ssa-ptr/pt_reference/references/sc_omp_global_nesting.htm))
- *loop worksharing* constructs nested inside  another *loop construct*

In case you are interested, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16995887/771663) the latter case is discussed more in details.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a design error.

A parallel for loop is not just N threads with N the number of cores for example, but potentially N*X threads, with 1 <= N*X < numsamples.

If you want an "iteration private" variable, then declare it just inside the loop-body (but you know that already); but declaring a thread-private variable for use inside a parallel for loop is probably not justified enough.